# Preference screen is white

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferencescreen

I tried to learn Android and decide to create SettingsActivity. But I got the problem that I cannot see any text at PreferenceScreen. My PreferenceScreen is white in design mode, so I cannot see any text there.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <PreferenceCategory app:title="@string/messages_header">

        <EditTextPreference
            app:key="signature"
            app:title="@string/signature_title"
            app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true" />

        <ListPreference
            app:defaultValue="reply"
            app:entries="@array/reply_entries"
            app:entryValues="@array/reply_values"
            app:key="reply"
            app:title="@string/reply_title"
            app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true" />

    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory app:title="@string/sync_header">

        <SwitchPreferenceCompat
            app:key="sync"
            app:title="@string/sync_title" />

        <SwitchPreferenceCompat
            app:dependency="sync"
            app:key="attachment"
            app:summaryOff="@string/attachment_summary_off"
            app:summaryOn="@string/attachment_summary_on"
            app:title="@string/attachment_title" />

    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory
        app:title="@string/help_header">
    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

[image: no text in design mode]

My project is almost empty and Android Studio was fresh installed.

Comment: Use `android:` attributes as far as possible, not `app:` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing. Text only started to appear after I replaced `app:title` with `android:title`. Problem is that I don't know why yet.